# Expansion of $ e^{\int f(t)\,dt} $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

What is the correct expansion of $ e^{\int f(t)\,dt} $ ?

Is it the following?

$$
\begin{split}
e^{\int f(t)\,dt}
 & \simeq 1+\int f(t)\,dt + \frac{1}{2}\left( \int f(t)\,dt\right)^2\\
 & =1+\int f(t)\,dt + \frac{1}{2}\iint f(t) f(t')\,dt\,dt'
\end{split}
$$

If yes, what are the conditions in the integral that this is true?

Comment: looks good to me, i suppose you should guarantee $f$ to be integrable

Comment: I suppose I also need $f^2$ to be integrable (bounded) so that Fubini's theorem holds and I can exchange the integrals?

Comment: yes, if you want to use Fubini.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the expansion of $e^x$ converges on all $\mathbb{C}$. The error of truncating the series is given by [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem). With regards to your integral it looks ok assuming your $f$ is not some funny function like a Gaussian or $x^x$ and has a manageable number of discontinuities.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate on why is Gaussian "funny"? It looks quite tame for me.

Comment: The Gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ is a function whose integral, even though it converges to a finite value on $(-\infty, \infty)$, to $\sqrt{\pi}$ to be exact, it's antiderivative $\int_0^x{e^{-t^2}dt}$ cannot be expressed as a nice, analytic function. It is usually just denoted as $\text{erf}(x)$ in case you ever come across it. If you are interested in looking it up, the value of $\sqrt{\pi}$ comes from a sneaky trick you can do with double integrals in polar coordinates.

Comment: This is the method, just take $\alpha=1$ http://www4.ncsu.edu/~franzen/public_html/CH331/help/gauss/gauss.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, but what does this have to do with the question? The OP didn't say anything about a closed-form expression, just the correctness of Taylor series.

Comment: He asked "what are the conditions in the integral that this is true?" and I replied with the explanation regarding the radius if convergence and Taylor's theorem. Taking a function like $f=\int{x^x dx}$, due to the rate at which it explodes in value one might have trouble getting sufficient approximation with just 3 terms. With regards to the Gaussian integral, it is just annoying to work with most of the time so it's there as a word of caution